# Nested query in Rails without using find_by_sql

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails

My sql query is

```
SELECT MAX(sale_money)
FROM (
    SELECT SUM(sale_money) sale_money
    FROM sales
    WHERE MONTH(created_at) = 5
    GROUP BY user_id
) t
```

I write the subquery in Rails 4 code:

```
record = Sale.select("SUM(sale_money) AS sale_money").where("MONTH(created_at) = 5").group(:user_id)
```

Someone could teach me query the `max_record` based on `record`, or another query, except `max_record = Sale.find_by_sql(my_raw_sql)` or `max_record = Sale.where(my_raw_sql)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the same can be done using Activerecord [form](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-from) method.

```
Sale.from(Sale.select("SUM(sale_money) AS sale_money")
               .where("MONTH(created_at) = 5")
               .group(:user_id), :t
         )
    .select("MAX(t.sale_money) as sale_money")
```

But, you can do as :

```
Sale.select("SUM(sale_money)")
    .where("MONTH(created_at) = 5")
    .group(:user_id)
    .order("SUM(sale_money) DESC")
    .limit(1)
```

The above one don't need the 2 *SELECT* queries.

Comment: the 2nd query is working. The 1st one may be wrong. Rails parse wrong SQL query: `SELECT `sales`.* FROM Sale.where("MONTH(created_at) = 5").select("SUM(sale_money) AS sale_money").group(:user_id)`. Thank you

Comment: Arup Rails understand `'Sale.select("SUM(sale_money) AS sale_money")
               .where("MONTH(created_at) = 5")
               .group(:user_id)'` like a string. So, it parse your code to: `SELECT MAX(t.sale_money) AS sale_money FROM Sale.select("SUM(sale_money) AS sale_money").where("MONTH(created_at) = 5").group(:user_id)`

Comment: @user4557573 It is working here.. what you meant not working, I am not getting you..

Comment: Yes, I forgot removing the apostrophe ('...') in your first way. Thank for teaching me :)

Comment: @user4557573 Thanks you saved my time!.. I am going to try why not working.. :)

Comment: Sorry for your time. And, I think you should update your 1st way with removing the apostrophe for other readers understand. I mean the 1st way should be `Sale.from(Sale.select("SUM(sale_money) AS sale_money")
               .where("MONTH(created_at) = 5")
               .group(:user_id), :t
         )
    .select("MAX(t.sale_money) as sale_money")`

Comment: @user4557573 where is the _apostrophe_ ? I still not able to find it.. may be overlooking.. can you edit it please ?

Comment: Arup. your answer is totally right now. Do we should remove the above comments?

Comment: @user4557573 Its ok.. don't need to delete. It is helpful.

Comment: Oke. I just want to keep your answer simple. Other readers not need care about the comments. Thank you again and sorry for my poor Eng :)